# An integral inequality?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $v \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $1 \ge v \ge 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb R} v \, dx = 1$.
I want to show that if
$$\int_{\mathbb R} v |v''|^2 \, dx < + \infty. \tag{$\star$}$$
then
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} |v v' v''' | \, dx < +\infty \tag{$\text{claim!}$}$$

If the absolute value were ''outside'' instead, the claim would be easy to prove: indeed, I would integrate by parts and get
$$
\Big|\int_{\mathbb R} v v' v''' \, dx \Big|= \Big|- \overbrace{\int_{\mathbb R} v'v' v'' \, dx}^A - \overbrace{\int_{\mathbb R} v |v''|^2 \, dx}^B \Big|. 
$$
Then we see that $A \equiv 0$ integrating again by parts, and $|B| < + \infty$ because of assumption ($\star$).

What can I do for the original claim? An idea is to write
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} |v v' v''' | \, dx  = \sup_{\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R), |\varphi|\le 1} \int_{\mathbb R}  \varphi v v' v''' \, dx,$$
but, if I do so, there's a difficulty in the integration by parts when the term $\varphi'$ arises.

Comment: Your claim has absolutely zero chance of being true -- it is generally impossible to bound higher derivatives via the lower derivatives (you can approximate a positive function with a very large $C^3$-norm and small $C^2$-norm via $C^\infty$-functions and then do some usual mumbo-jumbo to make your integral infinite)

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov This is unclear to me. Why is bounding $\Big|\int_{\mathbb R} v v' v'''dx \Big|$ much easier than $\int_{\mathbb R} |v v' v'''|dx $ then, when the "number of derivatives" in both expressions is the same?

Comment: Because of cancellations. You can integrate by parts a hundred times and get a hundredth derivative, but once you put absolute value inside you lose any chance for cancellations.

Comment: some weighted combination (e.g. by $2^{-n}$) of functions of the form $1 +\frac{1}{2} \sin x + N_n^{-2} \sin N_nx$ smoothly localized to disjoint unit intervals for a sequence of $N_n$ going rapidly  to infinity (e.g., $N_n = 2^n$) should generate a counterexample. (The $\frac{1}{2} \sin x$ factor is present to make sure $v', v''$ don't get too small too often.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}\newcommand{\om}{\omega}$Your claim is incorrect.

First, by vertical and horizontal rescaling, the conditions $1\ge v\ge0$ and $\int v=1$ can be relaxed to $v\ge0$ and $\int v<\infty$.

Next, for real $t$, let
\begin{equation}
    f_2(t):=e^{-t}(2+\sin(e^{3t}))\asymp e^{-t}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f_1(t):=-\int_t^\infty f_2\asymp -e^{-t}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f(t):=-\int_t^\infty f_1\asymp e^{-t},  
\end{equation}
so that $f'=f_1<0$ and $f>0$.

Now take any smooth function $h$ such that $h=0$ on $(-\infty,0]$ and $h=1$ on $[1,\infty)$, and let
\begin{equation}
    v:=fh. 
\end{equation}
Then $v\ge0$, $v=0$ on $(-\infty,0]$, and on $[1,\infty)$ we have
\begin{equation}
    v=f,\quad   v'=f_1,\quad    v''=f_2, 
\end{equation}
so that for real $t\ge1$
\begin{equation}
    v'''(t)=f'_2(t)=3e^{2t}\cos(e^{3t})-e^{-t}(2+\sin(e^{3t})) 
\end{equation}
and hence for real $t\ge1$
\begin{equation}
    |v'''(t)|\ge3e^{2t}|\cos(e^{3t})|-3. 
\end{equation}
So, $\int v<\infty$ and
\begin{equation}
    \int vv''^2<\infty,
\end{equation}
whereas
\begin{equation}
    \int |vv'v'''|\gg\int_1^\infty dt\,|\cos(e^{3t})|-O(1)=\infty. 
\end{equation}
Here $A\gg B$ means $B=O(A)$. $\quad\Box$

**Detail:** The latter displayed equality follows because $|\cos(e^{3t})|\ge\cos^2(e^{3t})=\frac12+\frac12\,\cos(2e^{3t})$ and
\begin{equation}
    \int_1^\infty dt\,\cos(2e^{3t})=\int_{2e^3}^\infty \frac{du}{3u}\,\cos u=-0.0053\ldots>-\infty. 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat explicit "physicist's" counterexample; the functions given are only piecewise $C^2$, with some jump discontinuities in the second derivatives. But for the integral inequality a standard mollification will give you true counterexamples to your claim.

First we note that the requirement $\int_{\mathbb{R}} v = 1$ is not strictly necessary: if the desired inequality holds, it will hold also if we relax the $v$ allowed to include all those with $\int_{\mathbb{R}} v \in [1/2,2]$.

Let $\Phi_0$ be a smoothed version of the tent function, so that outside $[-1,1]$ it vanishes, and on $[-1,1]$ it is approximately the function $1 - |x|$. Choose $\Phi_0$ such that it is linear on $[1/4,3/4]$ and on $[-3/4,-1/4]$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}$ be the function described below:

- Outside $[-1/4,1/4]$ it vanishes.
- Divide $[-1/4,1/4]$ into $N+1$ equal segments, label them from left to right in order as $I_0, \ldots, I_N$:

  - On $I_n$ when $1\leq n < N$ is odd, $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}$ is the unique quadratic polynomial that vanishes on the end points and has $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}'' = \epsilon$.
  - On $I_n$ when $1\leq n < N$ is even, $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}$ is the unique quadratic polynomial that vanishes on the end points and has $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}'' = -\epsilon$.
  - On $I_0$ and $I_N$ choose $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}$ to be a cubic polynomial such that $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}$ is overall $C^1$. Note that this unique polynomial has $|\Psi_{N,\epsilon}''| = O(\epsilon)$ and $|\Psi_{N,\epsilon}'''| = O(N\epsilon)$.

Let $v(x) = \Phi_0(x) + \Psi_{N,\epsilon}(x - 1/2) + \Psi_{N,\epsilon}(x+1/2)$.

We see easily that
$$ \int v|v''|^2 = \int\Phi_0 |\Phi_0''|^2 + O(\epsilon^2) $$
(Here we used that on the support of $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}$ we have $\Phi_0'' = 0$.)

Now, on $[-1/4,1/4]$, we have that $v''' = \Psi_{N,\epsilon}'''$ is given by $\delta$-functions of amplitude $\epsilon$ centered at the endpoints of the segments (except for $I_N$ and $I_0$, where $\Psi_{N,\epsilon}'''$ is size $N\epsilon$, but as those two intervals have width $\frac1N$ they contribute $O(\epsilon)$ to $\int v|v'v'''|$ and is negligible). On this interval we also have $v$ is $C^1$, and that $v - \Phi_0$ is of size $\epsilon$ in the $C^1$ norm. And so we have a lower bound
$$ \int v|v'v'''| \geq c \int |\Psi_{N,\epsilon}'''| \approx N \epsilon $$
as we have a total of approximately $N$ $\delta$-functions each with amplitude $\epsilon$.

Taking $N\to\infty$ for a fixed small $\epsilon$ we see that your claim is impossible.

Comment: I think your idea is of course the right one. However, as I understood the question, the function $v$ cannot depend on $N$ (or anything else). In other words, in a counterexample, we have to have $\int|vv'v'''|=\infty$ in actuality, rather than in potentiality, in a limit.

Comment: For each $N$ my function has compact support. Just take scaled and translated copies of a sequence of them.